# Spring Boot - two datasources configured - how to use second datasource?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have configured two schemas from MySQL database in my `Spring Boot` application and have marked one datasource as Primary.

Now, my question is how can I "use" second datasource? I am using `JpaRepository` based approach and when I try to save something to a table which resides in second DB schema, my Spring boot application always try to find this table in first DB schema and eventually throws table does not exist error.

P.S. I have marked second DB schema in my `Entity` class correctly.

Below is my `application.properties` file (prefix has been changed to omit confidential name):

```
# source 1
myframework.data.sql.connections.dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
myframework.data.sql.connections.dataSource.user=root
myframework.data.sql.connections.dataSource.password=root
myframework.data.sql.connections.dataSource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
myframework.data.sql.connections.dataSource.config.preferredTestQuery=select 1 from dual

# source 2
myframework.data.sql.connections.master.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
myframework.data.sql.connections.master.user=root
myframework.data.sql.connections.master.password=root
myframework.data.sql.connections.master.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: post `application.properties`

Comment: @JohnJoe: Posted

Answer (score 1):

Found solution on this Blog - [ScatterCode](https://scattercode.co.uk/2013/11/18/spring-data-multiple-databases)

The fix is that one has to *split* application configuration class into two and annotate each of the classes with what is shown below:

**Config class 1:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ MyServicefacadeProperties.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager", basePackages = {
    "com.myorg.foo" })
```

**Config class 2:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager", basePackages = {
            "com.myorg.foo.master" })
```

One dataSource should reside into first config class and second one in another. Also, move the Entity class and JpaRepository interface into respective packages as indicated in annotations above.

Cheers